# ckeditor doesn't load on public website

Tags: ckeditor

my ckeditor is working fine on localhost, but when I uploaded my website, it doesn't load at all. Here is the website which contains the ckeditor samples: http://iqdcconsultancy.co/test1/admin/ckeditor/samples/

Appreciate if someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

That URL works fine for me. Maybe clear your cache for that website, or check your console for errors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turned that the lang file en.js was empty. I uploaded it again and it worked just fine.